# Amount of devise user models with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, mongoid

I need to create 3 types of users: User, Moderator and Admin. I chose to make it with devise, Which of this will be better? Create 3 different devise user models or create 1 devise user model with field: type or rights?
In mongodb some fields can be blank, so i can create 3 forms in 1 devise model as I undesrstand and include only fields that i need?

Comment: It really depends on the requirements of your app. Generally roles are a better solution than separate user models.

Comment: You can go with role_model gem to add roles in your application https://github.com/martinrehfeld/role_model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this ?

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :role, type: Symbol, default: :regular

  validates_inclusion_of :role, :in => [:moderator,:admin,:regular]
  ...
```

I use [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) to allow user to have access to some functions depending of the role.

Good luck!